# The source code on Rust Book Chapter 17 may be wrong

Tags: rust, traits, box

Initially I use this tutorial as reference for some practice code.
After a few hours of troubleshooting I just plainly tried the code on that page as is.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html

```
pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}

pub trait Draw {
    fn draw(&self);
}

pub struct Button {
    pub width: u32,
    pub height: u32,
    pub label: String,
}

impl Draw for Button {
    fn draw(&self) {
        // code to actually draw a button
    }
}
pub struct Screen<T: Draw> {
    pub components: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Screen<T>
where
    T: Draw,
{
    pub fn run(&self) {
        for component in self.components.iter() {
            component.draw();
        }
    }
}

struct SelectBox {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    options: Vec<String>,
}

impl Draw for SelectBox {
    fn draw(&self) {
        // code to actually draw a select box
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let result = add(2, 2);
        assert_eq!(result, 4);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_tell_me(){
        let screen = Screen {
            components: vec![
                Box::new(SelectBox {
                    width: 75,
                    height: 10,
                    options: vec![
                        String::from("Yes"),
                        String::from("Maybe"),
                        String::from("No"),
                    ],
                }),
                Box::new(Button {
                    width: 50,
                    height: 10,
                    label: String::from("OK"),
                }),
            ],
        };
    
        screen.run();
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
warning: `decision-command-parser` (lib) generated 1 warning

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<SelectBox>: Draw` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:60:25
   |
60 |               components: vec![
   |  _________________________^
61 | |                 Box::new(SelectBox {
62 | |                     width: 75,
63 | |                     height: 10,
...  |
74 | |                 }),
75 | |             ],
   | |_____________^ the trait `Draw` is not implemented for `Box<SelectBox>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Draw`:
             Button
             SelectBox
```

bard.google.com says I need to add the trait to the Button, but the tutorial should be the source of truth given that it is "The Book" and all.

Comment: Can you explain what the book says (quote) that is wrong?

Comment: The `test_tell_me` code doesn't come from the book. Either use the trait object approach, with a `Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>` in which you put `Box::new (SelectBox {…})` and `Box::new (Button {…})`, or use the generic approach, with a `Vec<T: Draw>` in which you put either `SelectBox {…}` or `Button {…}` (but not both) _without boxing!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is quite clear, I think:

> ```rust
> pub struct Screen {
>     pub components: Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>,
> }
> ```
>
> On the `Screen` struct, we’ll define a method named `run` that will
> call the `draw` method on each of its `components`, as shown in
> Listing 17-5:
>
> ```rust
> impl Screen {
>     pub fn run(&self) {
>         for component in self.components.iter() {
>             component.draw();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This works differently from defining a struct that uses a generic type
> parameter with trait bounds. A generic type parameter can only be
> substituted with one concrete type at a time, whereas trait objects
> allow for multiple concrete types to fill in for the trait object at
> runtime. For example, we could have defined the Screen struct using a
> generic type and a trait bound as in Listing 17-6:
>
> ```rust
> pub struct Screen<T: Draw> {
>     pub components: Vec<T>,
> }
>
> impl<T> Screen<T>
> where
>     T: Draw,
> {
>     pub fn run(&self) {
>         for component in self.components.iter() {
>             component.draw();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This restricts us to a `Screen` instance that has a list of components
> all of type `Button` or all of type `TextField`. If you’ll only ever
> have homogeneous collections, using generics and trait bounds is
> preferable because the definitions will be monomorphized at compile
> time to use the concrete types.
>
> On the other hand, with the method using trait objects, one `Screen`
> instance can hold a `Vec<T>` that contains a `Box<Button>` as well as
> a `Box<TextField>`. Let’s look at how this works, and then we’ll talk
> about the runtime performance implications.

So, the generic approach can be used for a homogeneous collection, and the trait objects approach can be used for heterogeneous. You tried to use the generic approach with multiple types, which it cannot do, as the books says.

Comment: Thank you.  I think adding a heading to differentiate the two implementations would help.